# Funny characters in my db

Tags: database, postgresql, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

My web app is breaking when I try edit a certain content type and I'm pretty sure it is because of some weird characters in my database. So when I do:

```
SELECT body FROM message WHERE id = 666
```

it returns:

```
<p>â¢ <span></span></p><p><br /></p><p><em><strong>NOTE:</strong> Please remember to use your to participate in the discussion.</em></p>
```

However when I try to count how many documents have those characters postgres complains:

```
foo_450_prod=# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM message WHERE body LIKE'%â¢%';

ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe2a225
HINT:  This error can also happen if the byte sequence does not match the encodi
```

Does anybody know what the issue is and how I can query for those funny characters?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 666 is bad (https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Number_of_the_Beast).  Perhaps that's the problem? ;)

Comment: It's unclear where exactly you checked the result. In some DB admin tool? Which one? Try viewing DB content using PgAdminIII.

Comment: What is your database encoding?

Comment: @NinjaCat
The database encoding is utf-8 and my database is a big Iron Maiden fan so I don't think she has a problem with the 666 ;P

Comment: @BalusC the result was checked in psql command line tool, I can't use PgAdminIII because that db is in a server that won't allow me to connect remotely :(

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your `SELECT` statement is being interpreted as ISO-8859-1 or windows-1252.  In those encodings, 'â' == 0xE2, '¢' == 0xA2, and '%' == 0x25, which explains the 0xe2a225 byte sequence mentioned in the error message.

What's hard to figure out is why your first `SELECT` is returning an `â¢` to begin with.  It's an unlikely character combination to use on purpose, but it's also not a typical case of UTF-8/windows-1252 mojibake because E2 A2 isn't valid UTF-8.  It could be the first 2 bytes of a character, but that character would be a Braille dot pattern (U+2880 to U+28BF), which doesn't make sense there either.

Answer (score 0):

there's already a long way between your DB and printing some data from it in your webpage : your DB encoding may be ok, but you're probably trying here to print something originally in UTF-8 in ISO-8859-1 (and not "funny" characters). do you have something like :

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
```

in the `<head>` tag of your HTML page?

also, are you setting `SET NAMES 'utf8'` when connecting to your DB?

Comment: but you get the error only when you try a SELECT with the wrong encoding (LIKE'%â¢%'), right?

Comment: If the DB is utf-8, then it sure sounds like the web page is not in UTF-8.

Comment: yes, but the query I posted is one I'm using to investigate the issue on the database side not the one my webapp is using, sorry for the confusion. What is really puzzling me is that both of those characters are legal utf8 characters and pg won't let me query for it...